# How to style Buefy buttons to look like text links

Tags: vuejs2, buefy

I'm trying to style a Buefy button to look like a simple text-link.

For example, it is possible to use:

```
<b-button
    tag="a"
    type="is-text"
    href="https://www.example.com"
>
    Click here
</b-button>
```

This produces near the result I'm looking for, except I want to achieve a type such as `is-text-red` and `is-text-blue` to make the button appear as text of particular colours.

I could solve this by simply using:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" class="red-link">Click here</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com" class="blue-link">Click here</a>
```

But I want to use `<b-button type="is-text-red">` to make an inline link.

Can anyone point me in a direction that involves Bulma CSS and/or Buefy CSS modifications that would achieve this?

I'm looking at the node_modules BButton component, and it looks like the `type` prop is passed through, so it looks possible to create a custom type somewhere that would be analogous to `is-info` and `is-warning`.

I would like to have text-only versions such as `is-text-info` and `is-text-warning` so I can use the button component to place inline anchor tags.

Stated concisely, how does a person add another type to `<b-button>` that provides arbitrary styling?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is probably : *type="is-ghost"*. This renders the button as a simple text link without the padding and hover styles.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link(https://buefy.org/documentation/customization/). You might need to define your own css overrides.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. I'm almost in a position to work on this. I will update my answer if I can find a specific set of directions that works. Your URL is helpful because it shows that `// Links` annotation, which is at least a start somewhere specific.

Comment: Also, did you came across this link https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/
You can override and add classes from here.